# Microsoft Graph API gives unauthorized error while permissions are granted

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch information about my user's in a background function.

I use the following code to generate an access token, and then to fetch the specific user's info:

```
  const endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/oauth2/token'
  let clientId = 'my-client-id'
  let clientSecret = 'my-client-secret'
  let resource = 'https://graph.windows.net'

  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      url: endpoint,
      method: 'post',
      data: `client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=${resource}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })

    let accessToken = data.access_token

    const { adUserInfo } = await axios({
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/12345-67890-123456-123456-123456',
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    })
```

When executing this code I receive the response :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (D:\Websites\site\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\Websites\site\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\Websites\site\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...nVlANvJE16DRfr57A',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  ...
```

These are the  permissions granted to me by the application owner:
[image: permissions]

My thought process was that the User.Read or User.Read.All should be sufficient to call the /users/ API method?

UPDATE: I tried using Postman to do the request and got the following result, I don't know if it's relevant:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-08T09:36:04",
            "request-id": "the-request-id",
            "client-request-id": "the-client-request-id"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of `accessToken`? The error 401 usually means, that you are not authenticated - if you are missing permissions, you will get a 403

Comment: @MartinBrandl I am correctly receiving an accessToken, it looks like eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...E16DRfr57A.

Comment: Hm, you might try to perform the request using Graph-Tester https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I don't know how I need to enter the accessToken that is generated in there? Since my code will run from a CRON job, It's not a user logging in. When I perform the request by logging in with a test account, i can perfectly query the graph explorer using the same id with the website. But in this case I'm not logged in and don't find the option to paste my accessToken in the graph explorer for testing.

Comment: I believe your token request is missing `scopes`. Can you try by adding `&scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to `data` in your 1st request?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for the suggestion! I tried adding it, but the result stays the same. I have also tried putting the request in postman, and I have edited the response in my question at the bottom; I don't know if this is relevant information?

Comment: Also, please change your endpoint to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret.

Comment: You could try to insert the access token from the graph explorer and see whether it works with that

Comment: One last suggestion :) - Try to use MSAL.js and other SDKs provided by Microsoft instead of doing this all by yourself. Identity is complicated and there's a strong possibility of messing things up by doing things ourselves. I have been a culprit of doing this many times :P.

Comment: By changing the endpoint to /v2.0/ I am now receiving the code 403 "Forbidden" on my request to /users/<id> call. Does this mean the permissions that have been given to me are not sufficient?

Comment: Awesome. Some progress. Yes, 403 means just that. Looking at the permissions screenshot, you have given chosen "delegated" permission which means "on behalf of". Please delete those permissions and create same set of permissions but this time choose "application" instead of delegated. You will also need to do admin consent one more time. Please give that a try.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the help! I will pass this information on to my client who granted me these permissions, since I cannot change these myself.